# Adding a route that doesn't already exist using Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, url-routing

Say I have the following route in my file

```
app.get('/node/:id', function(req, res){

});
```

Say this id isn't recognised and so a route for it doesn't yet exist, as it doesn't yet exist in the database. What can I do to generate a route for this id and store the new ID in my database?

Comment: You can use the findOrCreate-Plugin to create any nodes (?) that aren't found: https://github.com/drudge/mongoose-findorcreate. But I think you're getting Mongoose and Express mixed up.

Comment: surely there's an app.post method of some sort I can use to just add that id into my database?

Comment: Express does have an `app.post()` method, yes. You can read about it in the express documentation: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.post.method. To add a new Object with Mongoose, you can call `YourModel.create()`. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, I'm very new to express and mongoose, and not sure how to approach the problem, I am familiar with the app.post method as I have researched this before asking the question